# ExtJS 4 - Getting the Selected item of a Menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building a web application where the user can select choices off of a menu. So far, I've been handling the menu item selection quite well. I can assign a selection listener to my menu item and do actions accordingly.

However, before I can do anything based off of the selection, I have to make the user log in first. The flow would be as such:

```
Menu Item Selection --> Log In --> Action based off of the menu selection
```

My main issue now is I can't seem to get the selected item from the menu. I've checked the Sencha Docs for this and the `Menu` doesn't seem to have a `getSelection()` method in it. I need to be able to fetch the selected item in my menu.

Does anyone know a work around for this scenario?

Comment: You can use the [`click`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-event-click) event.

Comment: @CD.. how exactly would I use the click event to fetch the selected item off of a menu?

Comment: Menu doesn't have a selected state, maybe you want a combobox instead. If not, you can add a hidden field and store clicked items there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just used Cookies to store the selected item.

During my onClick function, I did the following:

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set("key", value);
```

and then to fetch it later on I used

```
var key = Ext.util.Cookies.get("key");
```

This works for ExtJS 4.2, as for ExtJS 5 onwards, I think using `Ext.data.Session` might be more desirable.